# What information Chrome uses to show object type in `Sources` tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When debugging, I can see the following:

[image]

The first element is `Object`, and the others are `Item`. What information does Chrome use to show that type? The first item in array also was of `Item` type, but then I cloned it.
It's also interesting that both types have `Item` as prototype:

```
$scope.files[0] instanceof Item //true
$scope.files[1] instanceof Item //true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the Constructor function that was used to create the object. Native types have their own Constructors, but you can also create your own, eg:

```
var CustomThing = function () {
    this.name = 'A Custom Thing';
};

var list = [new CustomThing(), new CustomThing(), new CustomThing(), new CustomThing()];
console.dir(list);
```

Will log an `Array` of 4 `CustomThing` objects.

See [Details of The Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) for more info

See also this simple jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ht8frhz2/

Comment: yeah, that's why thought initially, but I tried that `$scope.files[1].constructor` in the console and it printed `function Object()  { [native code] }`, but it should have printed `function Item() {}`, if this was the case

Comment: That's odd - I tried the same thing and got the constructor logged as expected (see my updated link to jsfiddle). ??

Comment: Yeah, probably because you didn't clone the object. Thanks! Anyway, I'm more interested in the logic `Chrome` use to show the type. Let's see if there's anyone who knows that